# C++ char* error, program crashes

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

I am trying to write a program that stores char arrays of names.

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

char **names;
char *input_name;

int main() {
    names = new char*[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        names = new char[60];
        cout << "Input name" << i << ": \n";
        cin >> input_name;
        strcpy(names[i],input_name);
        cout << names[i] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Firstly I am getting the `cannot convert ‘char*’ to ‘char**’ in assignment
   names = new char[60];` error.

Also, getting the `invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
   strcpy(names[i],input_name);` error

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could modify my code and help me out

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `names = new char[60];` be `names[i] = new char[60];`? The other errors are side-effect of the previous error.

Comment: Good luck to you if the name is greater than 59 characters.

Comment: @alvits Thanks :), but I'm still getting errors in terms of input. My code is on IDEOne - http://ideone.com/PAMwgw

Comment: You have `input_name` uninitialized. In your case, it will be easier just to make it a simple string instead of a pointer. `char input_names[60];`.

Comment: Why use C++ at all if you don't want to use `std::string`?

Answer (score 2):

It's `names[i] = new char[60];` instead of `names = new char[60];`
And you forgot to init input_name with `input_name = new char[60];`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

char **names;
char *input_name;

int main() {
    names = new char*[10];
    input_name = new char[60];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        names[i] = new char[60];
        cout << "Input name" << i << ": \n";
        cin >> input_name;
        strcpy(names[i],input_name);
        cout << names[i] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you are using c++ you may should consider using std::string instead of char*. As mentioned by PaulMcKenzie in the comments you get into trouble when a name is longer than 59 characters . Plus std::string is more convenient IMO.

Comment: Why does my program crash if I don't do `input_name = new char[60];`? My program crashes at `cin >> input_name; strcpy(names[i],input_name)`

Comment: you just declared what input_name should be, but never assigned a value to it. As it is a pointer, it is pointing to an invalid memory address.

Comment: @H4kor This code still crashes my program. I modified the line `names = new char*[10]` to `names = new char*[value]` so that the user can input a number of names. If the user wants to input 5 names it works well, however if the user wants to input 12 names it crashes

Answer (score 0):

The code contains lots of memory leaks! Any data actually `new`ed should be `delete`d. Note that the form of `delete` needs to match the form of `new`, i.e., when an array object was allocated, an array object needs to release using, e.g., `delete[] names`.

When you read into a `char` array you need to make sure the amount of data in the array isn't exceed, you can limit the number of characters to be read by setting the stream's width, e.g.:

```
if (std::cin >> std::setw(60) >> names[i]) {
    // OK - do something with the data
}
else {
    // failed to read characters: do some error handling
}
```

Of course, in the code snippet you posted you try to reading into `input_name` which points nowhere: this will result in undefined (probably some crash).